# Selenium error: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <md-select>

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I know that I should find "select" element so I can choose from drop-down list, But here google trends don't provide "select" element and I want to choose any value from data and time list and When I try to do this I got this error 'Message: Select only works on  elements, not on '.... I found a solution but It was written by 'requests' module and I want to use selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe")


driver.get("https://trends.google.com/trends")

key1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sidenav-menu-btn"]/div')
key1.click()
time.sleep(1)

key2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sidenav-list-group-trends"]/md-item[2]/md-item-content/a/i')
key2.click()
time.sleep(2)


x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select_12"]')
x.click()

drp = Select(x)
drp.select_by_index(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab them by the `id` directly, instead of using `select`

```
drp = driver.find_element_by_id("select_option_22") # equates to 'Past 5 years'
drp.click()
```

That opened up the Past 5 years (using that unique `id`) when clicked

```
drp = driver.find_element_by_id("select_option_20") # equates to 'Past 30 days'
```

Would be the Past 30 days menu option, and so on....

Or, you can go for the text directly...

```
drp = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[normalize-space(text())='Past 7 days']")
drp.click()
```

Note the `normalize-space`, this is used to strip the white space which this element text value has.  It won't work without it.

Comment: can you tell me how I can get the ID for "United states" in country drop-down list in google trend..... So I can choose it

Comment: Try this xpath: `//md-option[@id='select_option_4']`